# NFC tag and NFC data format-Android

Tags: android, nfc

I started studying android NFC ,I am Confused about NFC tag(i think it is hardware component,Am i correct) and NFC data Format

1. Can any one list the types of NFC tags and NFC data Formats.
2. If NDEF is data format,Where it is possible to write in all NFC tags.

I am confused about NDEF and Mifare whether they are tags or data Format.

Thanks.

Comment: NDEF editor: https://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/

Comment: It appears the data format effectively breaks some apps. For instance, NFC tools cannot write to a card without NDEF format. NXP TagWriter can format the WhizTags Mifare tags, after which NFC tools can read/write the tag, and reports NDEF support.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 4 standard NFC tag types:
Type 1, Type 2, Type 3, Type 4
They differ in how you access data on them, and on the communication frame work you use to talk to them. (This gets into the mechanics of how data is exchanged)
Mifare is a proprietary standard made by NXP
Mifare Ultralite is a type 2 tag

The tags differ in the maximum amount of data you can store on them, and the maximum amount of data that can be exchanged per command (Type 2 tags can read 16 bytes at a time, and can write 4 bytes at a time)

NDEF is a way of formatting data on the tags. Mifare and the 4 tag types can all be formatted to store data in a NDEF format.

Android recognizes these tag types when you use the NDEF class for accessing and filtering tags it scans.

Not all Nfc tags (even the standard ones and Mifare) will be set up for Ndef, or will hold Ndef formatted data. But Android automates this process, so you don't have to worry about what type of tag you have, only if it can store Ndef data on it.

Mifare, as a proprietary standard, is not guaranteed to have it's own class in Android, so you may have to write your own stack for accessing it on a phone. (Nexus S supports Mifare, and can write Ndef data to it, if you are wondering.)

I hope this helps.

Comment: To clarify the Mifare Standard issue: Hardwware support for this tag-type is not required by the NFC standard, and in fact all non-NXP NFC controller chips that I know about don't support Mifare classic at all. Writing your own software stack is not possible because no communication to the tag will be possible. Background is, that NXP asks for a license-fee for their broken CRYTO-1 algorithm that is required for Mifare communication. Noone wants to pay NXP for a broken crypto-algo, so they just drop support for the optional technology.

Comment: And another thing: Android has NDEF support for the ISO15693 tags as well. These are not part of the NFC standard (yet), but they work well, are widely available and come in lots of different sizes. In the Android-world they go by the name NFC-V.

Comment: That's interesting. I knew they could read NFC-V tags, but I didn't know that support for them had been added to their NDEF support. Good to know.

Comment: @Ben Hi I've an android app that reads NFC tags and works fine. i can write to the payload and read from it. The trouble is the old system that uses nokia c700 can read unformatted tags for the tagID. Android has a problem doing this. Do i need to format the tag before android can read the TagID? Thanks